# Could not Delete image from directory using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to delete an image from directory using following statement

```
System.IO.File.Delete(Path);
```

i have previously accessed this image in another function

```
Image image=Image.FromFile(imagePath)
imageList1.Images.Add(image);
```

but it shows an error that file is locked by another process. I searched for this and find out that I should use using to dispose of the image object so i tried this

```
using(Image image=Image.FromFile(imagePath))
    imageList1.Images.Add(image);
```

but this gives me an error in program.cs that paramter is not valid and programs doesnot run.
and sometime it gives the error
Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.

I am adding the imagelist to a list view and before deleting the file i am clearing all the items of both imagelist and listview with following commands.

```
imageList1.Images.RemoveByKey(imageName);
imageList1.Images.Clear();
listView1.Items.RemoveByKey(imageName);
listView1.Items.Clear();
listView1.SmallImageList = null;
```

this is my code where i am populating listview.

```
try
        {
            string album = albumListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            List<string> imageName=new List<string>();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/image.xml");
            XmlNodeList list = null;
            list = doc.SelectNodes(string.Format("/images/image"));
            listView1.Columns.Clear();
            listView1.Columns.Add("Image List",210,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            imageList1.Images.Clear();
            listView1.MultiSelect = false;
            foreach (XmlNode node in list)
            {
                if (node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText == album)
                {
                    string imagePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\images\\" + album + "\\" + node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                    Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
                        imageList1.Images.Add(image);
                    imageName.Add(node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(imageName[j],imageName[j],j);
                listView1.View = View.Details;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Images in this Album Please add the Images");
            showImage.Hide();
        }
```

and this is the code where i want to delete the file

```
var listItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        string album = albumListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string imageName = listItem.Text;
        string imagePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\images\\" + album + "\\" + imageName;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/image.xml");
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//image[./imageName/text()='" + imageName + "' and ./album/text()='" + album + "']"));
        if (node != null)
        {
            //remove image from directory tooV
            doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(node);
            doc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/image.xml");
            imageList1.Images.RemoveByKey(imageName);
            imageList1.Images.Clear();
            listView1.Items.RemoveByKey(imageName);
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].Remove();
            imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
            listView1.SmallImageList = null;
            fillImageList();
            System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
            MessageBox.Show("Image deleted");
            fillAlbumList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far as the image is still referenced in imagelist1, it is not disposed. In order to properly dispose it, you will have to dispose the imagelist1 also. Then only all the reference to Image are closed.

Comment: Well, I have not seen the entire code but it sometime happens that .net objects are still alive due to non-deterministic behavior of GC. I have one suggestion, though not tried myself, try manually disposing the image object before deleting the file.

Comment: Plz see the updated qstn i have tried to dispose off the object but no luck

Comment: I have tried disposing off the image object manually but it gives the same eror in program.cs

Comment: do you get the error on this line ? "imageList1.Images.Add(image);"

Comment: no if i dispose the image object i got error in program.cs in this line 
Application.Run(new ImageCollector());

Comment: Please post the entire code if possible so I could help you out with this

Comment: Please give me some time so I can actually run the code and try to see what is the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not find out the solution to your problem. I tried several ways to work around it. The only one seems to be working is wait for some time and then delete the files. For some reason, it allows deletion after some time. May be this fact help someone else to give a better answer

Comment: yes i am thinking of the same lets see if any other person can work it out otherwise its the only option